# Passing prop value after switching tabs

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

I have one header page that has two tabs. The two tabs direct to two different pages. I am using the `area` prop that I defined in the header page router view for the system page. It works fine when I am on the system page, but when I go to the product tab and come back to system tab, the prop in the system tab
loses the value. It shows as the string `"area"` in the prop. I would like to get the same value when I switch tabs.

```html
    <div class="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li @click="$router.push({ name: 'system' })">
          <a>SYSTEM</a>
        </li>
        <li @click="$router.push({ name: 'product' })">
          <a>Product</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <router-view :area="area"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

System view:

```js
export default {
props: ['area'],
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for keep-alive

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using @click binding you will be much better off using `<router-link>` especially since you are using the `router-view`

this will allow you to pass params simply in your app.

https://router.vuejs.org/api/

you declare your routes like so

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/glossary/:subjectName',
    name: 'glossaryWithParams',
    component: GlossaryPage,
  },
]
```

Then in your code you can build the  element simply like so:

````
 <router-link
  :to="`/glossary/${subjectName}`"
  class="tabs__link"
>
    Subject Glossary
</router-link>
    ```

Once you implement Router-link your history push state will also be resolved, and your params will work normally.
````

Comment: Could you kindly provide little more details.

Comment: just read the documentation, you need to replace your @click `li's` with router-links